# RuntimeError: latex was not able to process the following string: b'$1.0$'

Tags: python, matplotlib

MCVE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc

plt.rc('text', usetex = True)
plt.plot([1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0])
plt.show()
```

Error thrown is as described in the title:

```
RuntimeError: latex is not able to process the following string:
b'$1.0$'


Here is the full report generated by latex:



<Figure size 432x288 with 1 Axes>
```

Error raises due to the `usetex` setting set to `True`. If set to `False`, error does not happen.

I have no idea why this happens, I think (not sure) the same code would have worked fine a couple weeks ago.

Adding some more info:

The code points out the error on a line:

```
exc=exc.output.decode('utf-8')))
```

Comment: $ is a reserved character in latex. Try adding a backslash in front of it?

Comment: @ar7 there's not any '$' in my code...

Comment: Ignore that first comment. Of course `$` is a latex command and `$1.0$` is valid latex, so it should work. Did you do anything to your installation lately? Is TeX running fine by itself?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Not that I know of. I've only writing and rewriting codes. I just checked environment variables and they seem good. I use miktex distribution, also (I'm not sure what you mean by TeX running fine by itself). I just compiled one old .tex document I had and it ran with no issues.

Comment: Is latex in your path? I.e. if you cd to the directory you're running this python code from and type `latex -help`, does it work?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest In my path I already had `...miktex\miktex\bin\x64` and just added `...miktex` to see if it made any change. Typing `where latex` in cmd points to `...miktex\miktex\x64\latex.exe`). I just ran `latex -help` inside the directory where I run the code and it seems it "processes" something but doesn't print anything in the terminal.

Comment: Ok, so `latex -help` should obviously print the help options. If it doesn't, it means you will need to find out why that is.  I suppose once that is solved, it will also be able to process your matplotlib strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling miktex fixed the issue, although the cause for the occurrence is unknown.